# Login page go directly to cache because of cookies

Tags: javascript

I have a login button that opens a new window to a third-party login page. If i. Logged in first time, any time i refresh the page or open the website in a new tab when i click on the button it redirects me to the cached login response data, and i have to clear both my website and the login website cookies completely(website+external ones(google cookies.. etc))..

So is there is a way to force clearing all website data from javascript? Or any way to avoid this caching issue?

I have already tried to delete document.cookie but it only delete only the domain cookie not the external ones.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, an app with a third party authentication flow is like from your app, you check the credentials in your cookie to see whether they are valid.

If they are not valid or do not exist, open the third party authentication dialog then login. After a successful login, mostly, the 3rd party auth should saved something in the cookie with its domain. And you also need to save something about credentials in the cookie.

If there are valid credentials in your cookie, then you are simply authorised and the credentials in the cookie should be good to use.

Back to your 2 questions, `So is there is a way to force clearing all website data from javascript? Or any way to avoid this caching issue?`
Why do you need to clear those data for the sake of authentication?
For the second question, I think I answered it already with the general introduction.